# File not loading after deploying on Heroku. Runs fine on localhost and heroku local web

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I made an API using Flask that provides predictions using a pre-trained Scikit-learn model. The API works fine on local host and on Heroku local web but fails to load the model when I deploy it. API returns prediction in the form of JSON. `{"prediction":123}` is returned when run locally. `{"error":"Failed to load model"}` is returned when it is deployed.

Apps architecture:

```
 - houseprediction.py
 - waitressServer.py
 - requirements.txt
 - Procfile
 - supp-files:
    - gbModel.pkl 
    - model_columns.pkl
    - sectorLabels.pkl
```

houseprediction.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])

def predict():
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    try:
        gbModel = joblib.load("{}\\supp-files\\gbModel.pkl".format(dir_path))
    except:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to load model'})
    try:
        model_columns = joblib.load("{}\\supp-files\\model_columns.pkl".format(dir_path))
    except:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to load model columns'})
    try:
        lbl = joblib.load("{}\\supp-files\\sectorLabels.pkl".format(dir_path))
    except:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to load sector labels'})
    json_ = request.get_json()
    query_df = pd.DataFrame(json_, index=[0])
    pd.options.display.max_columns = 50
    query_df['sector'] = lbl.transform([query_df['sector']])[0]
    print(query_df.dtypes)
    query = pd.get_dummies(query_df)
    for col in model_columns:
         if col not in query.columns:
              query[col] = 0
    print(query_df.shape)
    print(query_df.head(1))
    prediction = gbModel.predict(query)
    print(prediction)
    return jsonify({'prediction': prediction[0]})

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Welcome to House Prediction"
```

waitress.py:

```
from waitress import serve
import os
import housepredictionServer     
serve(housepredictionServer.app, port=os.environ['PORT'])
```

Procfile: `web: python waitressServer.py`

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: chage all paths to  `supp-files/{file}.pk1`

Comment: @SmartManoj Oh wow that worked. I have been stuck on this for a while and it never occurred to me that the servers mostly use unix based systems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all paths to `supp-files/{file}.pk1` since heroku is an unix based system